# How can I use XAML 2009 as design data in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I have a xaml file which I want to use as DesignData (with design-time creatable types).
I also want to use XAML 2009 features in it, however Visual Studio does not seem to accept it, complaining that the attributes I want to use do not exist in the target namespace.

Here is what my xaml file looks like:

```
<my:ViewModel 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:MyCompany"
>
    <my:ViewModel.ViewCollection>
        <!-- That part does not work, because it tells me that FactoryMethod and Arguments could not be found in the namespace for prefix 'x'. -->
        <my:BusinessObjectView x:FactoryMethod="my:BusinessObjectView.Convert">
            <x:Arguments>
                <my:BusinessObject />
            </x:Arguments>
        </my:BusinessObjectView>
    </my:ViewModel.ViewCollection>
    <my:ViewModel.BoCollection>
        <!-- Even though the x:TypeArguments syntax for defining objects only appears in XAML 2009, that part works fine - probably because the TypeArguments attribute already existed in that namespace. -->
        <scg:List x:TypeArguments="my:BusinessObject">
            <my:BusinessObject />
        </scg:List>
    </vm:ViewModel.BoCollection>
</my:ViewModel>
```

And here is the fragment in the XML project file that describes the build action:

```
<DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreatableTypes Include="Path/To/File.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
</DesignDataWithDesignTimeCreatableTypes>
```

So, what is the problem?
Is it the namespace prefix? (In which case, which one should I use for XAML 2009?)
Is it the build action?
Is my whole approach flawed?

Answer (score 2):

"Loose XAML file" is a concept which is orthogonal to the concept of XAML 2009.
Loose XAML file is a XAML-only (no code behind) file which is loaded at run-time. http://wpf.2000things.com/2010/10/20/100-loose-xaml-files/
XAML 2009 is an version of the XAML language and a set of corresponding schemas.

To make .xaml file "loose" you just need to stop it being compiled (in file properties). 
To load loose .xaml file you need to use `XamlReader.Load` Method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.load.aspx http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/understanding-uncompiled-xaml-to-design-dynamic-ui-in-wpf/
Strangely it seems that XAML2009 files still use the 2006 schemas.

Comment: The thing is, I am not talking about XAML that will be used to define the UI of the application - I want to use that XAML file as Design Data, which is only loaded by Visual Studio, never at runtime. I cannot modify Visual Studio in the way that it loads my file. But you are right - the concepts are orthogonal.

Comment: "I am not talking about XAML that will be used to define the UI of the application". Neither am I. XAML is a general purpose serialization format. Is your problem with referencing a XAML2009 file in a normal compiled XAML file as the DesignData? If so, are you specifying it like `mc:Ignorable="d"` `d:DataContext="{d:DesignData source=./loose.xaml}"`?

Comment: It has been more than a year since I last worked on the project that had that. If I remember correctly, I think that there was no problem in referencing and using the design data - the issue was that the Visual Studio XAML editor was insistent in highlighting perceived errors in perfectly valid XAML 2009 markup.